# Sharepoint 2016 Failing in configuration step 3 out of 10

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

So i'm attempting to configure 2016 sharepoint... Once I get through the steps of adding the information for the single server farm, database etc, it basically fails.

I've checked to ensure that the account has the proper access, it get's as far as actually MAKING the database on the SQL server.  However, once it hits 3 / 10 for actually configuring the database it stops.  I'm going to attach a log and any help is appreciated!

PS C:\Users\adam.abraham> 05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                    Found parameter B2B_UPGRADE in collection
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  Leaving function Command.this[string key]
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  My cached Farm object is null, so will load it
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  Calling SPFarm.Local and SPServer.Local to get the local farm objects
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  SPFarm.Local returned null.  This usually means that the server is not joined.  But, you can delete a server from

the configdb without unjoining, which would mean that this machine still thinks it is joined.
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  Trying to access the server farm connection string
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  Entering function TaskCommon.TryGetWssVersion4ConnectionStringExists
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                    Entering function RegistryHelper.RegistryHelper
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                      The RegistryHelper has the key name as Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\16.0\Secure

\ConfigDB and the registry hive as LocalMachine
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                    Leaving function RegistryHelper.RegistryHelper
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                    Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 registry key Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions

\16.0\Secure\ConfigDB for the connection string does not exist
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                    Unable to get the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 connection string
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  Leaving function TaskCommon.TryGetWssVersion4ConnectionStringExists
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  DID NOT discover a v4 connection string and SPFarm.Local indicates that this machine is not joined.
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  Entering function Farm.Clear
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                    Entering function CentralAdminServiceInstance.Reset
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                    Leaving function CentralAdminServiceInstance.Reset
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                  Leaving function Farm.Clear
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                                Leaving function Farm.TryIsJoinedToFarm
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                              Leaving function Farm.IsJoinedToFarm
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                              Creating connection string for config db SharepointDBi server s0077.dbiservices.com
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                              Creating connection string for admin content db SharePoint_AdminContent_452f1541-d117-41c7-8323-b4cb3f3ee7ef server

s0077.dbiservices.com
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                              Using NTLM for sql connection string
05/30/2017 14:35:36  9  INF                              Creating a new farm with config db SharepointDBi content db SharePoint_AdminContent_452f1541-d117-41c7-8323-

b4cb3f3ee7ef server s0077.dbiservices.com for farm mode
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                              Farm.ServerRoleOptional = False
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                              Now joining to farm at server s0077.dbiservices.com database SharepointDBi
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                              Entering function Command.this[string key]
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                                Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                                  Found value in collection for key localserverrole
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                                Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                                Found parameter localserverrole in collection
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                              Leaving function Command.this[string key]
05/30/2017 14:37:55  9  INF                              The parameter localserverrole is chosen, so returning the value as SingleServerFarm
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  ERR                              Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception 
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  ERR                              Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisServerManager.CommitChanges(ApplyChanges applyChanges)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionApplicationPool(String name, SecurityIdentifier sid, String password,

SPIisApplicationPoolSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool.ProvisionLocal(SPIisWebServiceApplicationPoolProvisioningOptions options)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.ProvisionApplicationInstance()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.ProvisionLocal(SPServiceInstance serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceApplication.ProvisionLocal(SPServiceInstance serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join(Boolean skipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost, Nullable`1 serverRole)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information:

{1}
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                    Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                    Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information:

{1}
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  INF                              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
05/30/2017 14:38:17  9  ERR                              An exception of type System.ArgumentException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Value does not fall

within the expected range.
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisServerManager.CommitChanges(ApplyChanges applyChanges)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionApplicationPool(String name, SecurityIdentifier sid, String password,

SPIisApplicationPoolSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool.ProvisionLocal(SPIisWebServiceApplicationPoolProvisioningOptions options)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.ProvisionApplicationInstance()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.ProvisionLocal(SPServiceInstance serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceApplication.ProvisionLocal(SPServiceInstance serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join(Boolean skipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost, Nullable`1 serverRole)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: is the account you are using for the psconfig an administrator on the sql box with the dbcreator and Securityadmin roles on the sql instance?

Comment: Yup, I have it using the DB creator, securityadmin and sysadmin roles.

Comment: what does the error log say? It should be in the logs folder as `Upgrade -*-error.log`

Comment: Do you mean on the sharepoint server or the SQL server?

Comment: sharepoint server

Comment: So Mike, i'm going under Windows : Logs - Otherwise there isn't a specific sharepoint folder where the logs are located.  Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: It's originally under `c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\<SP Number>\Logs`

Comment: Hello Mike - So theres the DSCDiagnotistic logs and other logs in there as well, nothing with an Upgrade appended infront.   I can't even chat with you because my reputation is at a 1 - if you could email me so we don't have an extended discussion here?  abra4242@gmail.com or adam.abraham@dbiservices.com is my skype for business.